# Copy Swift object storage container to new openstack service

Tags: backup, openstack, openstack-swift

I have two OpenStack services, hosted by different providers and I'm trying to figure out the best way to copy an entire container from one service to the other.

Right now I'm looking at two options:

1. Somehow use the swift cli to copy the container from one service to another
2. Download the entire container to my local environment and upload to the new container

I don't know if option 1 is even feasible but I would really prefer it, I can't find any documentation saying that the cli would even support this.

The second option is really unattractive, but might be the easiest. I was looking into downloading a backup and then uploading that to my new service.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the container-to-container feature can be used but I believe it would require collaboration from the cloud operators: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_container_sync.html

Alternatively [rclone](http://rclone.org/docs/) may come in handy.

Comment: Ended up using rclone. Thanks for the recommendation!